# Differentiabilty only at a single point implies the jacobian is singular?

Tags: analysis

let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function differentiable at a single point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ yet not differentiable at any other point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The inverse function theorem tells us that if the jacobian of $f$ is non singular at $p$ then $f$ differentiable on some open set that contains $p$.

So this means the jacobian of $f$ in our case must be singular.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The inverse function theorem tells us that if the jacobian of $f$ is non singular at $p$ then $f$ differentiable on some open set that contains $p$.

The differentiability of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $p$ is part of the premises of the inverse function theorem, not a conclusion of the invertibility of the derivative in one point.

Indeed, a function can be differentiable in a single point and have nonsingular Jacobian at that point.

For $n = 1$, consider a continuous nowhere differentiable function $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ like the [Weierstraß function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Then for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ the function

$$f(x) = (x-t)\cdot g(x)$$

is differentiable in $x = t$, with derivative $f'(t) = g(t)$, and nowhere else. If $g(t) \neq 0$, the derivative is nonsingular.

For general $n$, choose points $t_1,\dotsc,t_n$ with $g(t_i) \neq 0$ and let

$$f(x) = ((x_i-t_i)\cdot g(x_i)).$$

Then $f$ is differentiable in the point $(t_1,\dotsc,t_n)$ and nowhere else, and its Jacobian is nonsingular.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!